# Pandas how to use column name in output string

Tags: python, pandas

Real simple question that I cant seem to get. For the following single column DF:

```
Cost  
1
```

What syntax would I use to print "Cost = 1". i know print df['Cost'] would be 1. But i want the column name to be in the output.

Comment: What do you want if the column has more than one row?

Comment: well if it has more than one thats fine. i just want to be able to call whatever column's header when i call the value

Answer (score 2):

This is one way without having to reference your column name(s) explicitly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cost': [1]})

for k in df:
    print('{0} = {1}'.format(k, df[k].iloc[0]))

# Cost = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product':['x','y'],'Cost': [1,2]})
col_names=df.columns
for row in range(0,len(df)):
    for col_name,col in zip(col_names,df.iloc[row]):
        print("{}={}".format(col_name,col))
```